# boto3 Dynamodb table batch insert missing something

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I expected something like this to work.  I am adding 26 items to a dynamo db using boto3 interface.

But I am missing something because the code reports 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'batch_write_item'`
right at the 25th insert (which should have auto-flushed the buffer)

```
from boto3.dynamodb import table
items = [
{'key': 1, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 2, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 3, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 4, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 5, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 6, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 7, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 8, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 9, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 10, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 11, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 12, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 13, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 14, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 15, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 16, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 17, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 18, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 19, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 20, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 21, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 22, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 23, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 24, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 25, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'},
{'key': 26, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'}
]

with table.BatchWriter('my_tbl_name',"us-east-1") as tbl:
    for r in items:
        tbl.put_item(r)
```

I have also tried with `tbl.put_item(str(r))`  and a few other things like JSON encode...  but no luck. Does anyone know of a simple working example?   Yes I looked but there is lots of mixing between Boto and Boto3.

Comment: Your `items` list is not a valid syntax. Don't know why didn't get a syntax error. Each element in the list is not a valid dictionary. `{'key': 1), u'timestamp': '1493269200000')}`. What is that extra closing bracket in each value? Shouldn't it be `{'key': 1, u'timestamp': '1493269200000'}`

Comment: Thanks...   Looks like a pasted poorly I fixed the code snippet

Comment: ________________

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All I needed was an instance of a `Table` The camel `BatchWriter()` was giving me the wrong kind of object for the context.  I needed `batch_writer()`

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('staging.tstable3')
print(table.creation_date_time)

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for r in items:
        batch.put_item(Item=r)
```

Comment: If it is batch writer then why invoke `put_item` for each item?  Shouldn't it be `batch.put_items(items)`  or similar (don't know exact method name)?

Comment: It looks like the context manager handles this. The `put_item` method call doesn't do the insert, it only loads it into the buffer. When the context manager closes, the batch is processed. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.batch_writer